# Calling C# code method with parameters in javascript using razor

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to call a C# method in my javascript code and also trying to pass parameter to it using razor syntax but not able to do it correctly. Below is my code:

```
function RecallNoFmatter(cellvalue) {
    var value = @(Precall.S300FormatRecall(+cellvalue+));
    return value;

}
```

I get  this error message:

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'cellvalue' does not exist in the current context.

Can someone tell me the correct syntax of how to pass parameter in above?

Comment: What in the world is `+cellvalue+` supposed to mean?

Comment: Based on your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123852/jquery-template-tags-use-with-lambda-expressions-under-html-helper-extensions-in), you are **grossly** misunderstanding server vs client side code and what the relationship between them is.  You should take a step back and try to understand those two concepts, and then these things will seem much simpler and more obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# runs server-side. The `@` code is running server-side before the script is delivered to the client and has no access to the JavaScript values.

Your JavaScript runs client-side and has no ability to call server-side methods.

If you want to expose server-side functionality to the client, you're going to have to use AJAX and provide some service for the client to call.